# Nomear tabela resultante de SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer um *SELECT* da tabela resultante de outro *SELECT*, mas preciso referenciá-lo no *ON* do *INNER JOIN*. Como faço isso no Oracle (PL/SQL)? Tentei desta seguinte forma, mas não deu certo:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM recurso WHERE tipo = 'CID') AS cidade INNER JOIN hierarquia ON hierarquia.recurso = cidade.codigo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve posicionar o `Subselect` na frente do `INNER JOIN` e depois você pode dar um apelido para sua seleção como se fosse uma tabela.

```
SELECT * 
FROM hierarquia 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT *
   FROM recurso 
   WHERE tipo = 'CID'
) Cidade
ON Cidade.codigo = hierarquia.recurso
```

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0f0c8/1)